# Can I disable OEM lock from computer?

Tags: rooting, root-access, installation, operating-system

Can I disable the OEM lock of my Samsung Galaxy S8+ from my computer?

Comment: https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3659305 // https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=4060701

Answer (score 2):

For security reasons the only way to change the option "Allow OEM unlock" is from within the running device in the developer settings menu.